# Panoramas and Arrays of Images

Tags: c#, arrays, image, windows-phone, panoramas

So I have a coding problem I need help with, and simply put I have no idea what I am doing with this. FYI, I am not using the toolkit with the gesture listeners.

I have a panorama page with 3 panorama items:  BigImageCenter, BigImageLeft, BigImageRight.

In my application are a bunch of images which will be downloaded with the app. The goal on this panorama page is to have a scrollviewer set at the bottom of the page to show the entire list of images that come with the app in little thumbnails, and the top part of the page to be the panorama items, where if you flick left or right the images methodically advance (or go back if flicking left) down the list.

Also, if you tap on one of the thumbnails in the bottom scrollviewer, it will replace that current panorama image with that thumbnail image. If you flick left or right on the panorama page, you will then get that thumbnail image's -1 or +1 in the array.

The first image you see on the page is BigImageCenter.

I do not have to use 3 panorama items, and I might be able to get away with just 1. However when testing it with just 1, after I change the image by clicking on a thumbnail and swiping the panorama left or right, the next image about to load on screen is always the same image before it was changed (makes sense, since I have not coded any array to dynamically change the next image, etc).

However I have no idea how to do any of the following:

1) Create an array where the first image in the panorama item is set to X.
2) Tell if the user flicked left or right to -1 or +1 in the array
3) Set the thumbnail image to replace the current panorama image when tapped, and then throw the array to that thumbnail image position.

Here is the XAML of both the panorama control and the thumbnail scrollviewer:

```
<Grid x:Name="ControlPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="-8,-22,-49,90">
        <controls:Panorama Name="Image_Panorama" Height="auto" Width="auto">
            <!--Panorama item one-->
            <controls:PanoramaItem>
                <Rectangle Height="auto" Width="auto" x:Name="BigImageCenter">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="image030.jpg" />
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>

            <controls:PanoramaItem>
                <Rectangle Height="auto" Width="auto" x:Name="BigImageLeft">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="pics/image002.jpg" />
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>


            <controls:PanoramaItem>
                <Rectangle Height="auto" Width="auto" x:Name="BigImageRight">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="pics/image003.jpg" />
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>


        </controls:Panorama>     
    </Grid>



<Grid x:Name="MiniPicturePanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,390,0,0">
 <ScrollViewer x:Name="svSmall" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
  <StackPanel x:Name="smallImages" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="330,0,0,0">

     <Rectangle Height="70" Width="110" Margin="0,0,30,0" StrokeThickness="3" MouseLeftButtonUp="smallImage_Tap" Stroke="#FF004080" x:Name="Bat1">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="image030.jpg" />
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>


     <Rectangle Height="70" Width="110" Margin="0,0,30,0" StrokeThickness="3" MouseLeftButtonUp="smallImage_Tap" Stroke="#FF004080" x:Name="Bat2">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="pics\image002.jpg" />
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
```

.... and so forth

Now I Have some things done, but not to the way I'd like:

MouseLeftButtonUp="smallImage_Tap"  is a function which will change the panorama item for "BigImageCenter" to the current image.fill of the rectangle. I just cannot code it to change the current pivot item in view. I need help with that.

```
private void smallImage_Tap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    BigImageCenter.Fill = (sender as Rectangle).Fill;
```

In case you are wondering why I am using rectangles, it was the easiest way for me to change the image with the code behind when tapping on the smaller thumbnail.

And that is pretty much my codebehind. I am literally doing this dynamic coding from scratch, and need some help achieving this dream.

PS: I also need to know the array number tied to the image so that I can allow the user to "Favorite" it and place it in another page.

Comment: Anyone with any suggestions? I think I read that it is impossible to actually accomplish this? By this, I mean that if I have 3 pivotitems, that I cannot assign images to each of these items and have them jump to that spot in the array? Arghhh!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will cause you problems with certification, even if you do get it to work (assuming I'm understanding you correctly.)  It's a non-standard use of the panorama.

I think a better solution is a fully custom control using gestures...it's not that difficult to do, and you'll have full control over the presentation.  It'll be far easier to do this than hack the pano to do what you want.

Good luck,
John